# Simple bridge between two eth ports

Tags: networking, network-manager

I have PC1 (Ubuntu 20.04) with two ethernet controllers. I want them to work like simple switch. eth0 connected to router while eth1 connected to another PC2. I want PC2 has access to local network and internet as well.
To do that I have to bridge the connections. I think [this manual](https://www.xmodulo.com/configure-linux-bridge-network-manager-ubuntu.html) is quite good to follow, but its still unclear which eth should I enslave and which to remove? I don't want to do it with trial and errors, so I'm asking for some clarifications.

Comment: May using your own pc as a dhcp server could be an acceptable solution for you?

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup ip forwarding. Data received on eth1 must be forwarded to eth0 using the routing table of your linux box.
You have to change the content of the file /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward to 1 and then add some rules to the linux firewall via iptables. Search the web, it is full of tutorials. Probably, inside your router, there is a little linux distro doing the same.

You could also setup a bridge switch, with the command ip, there is also a gui for network manager that allow to do the same, try the command nm-connection-editor.

Comment: Your question might be more useful if you could point the OP to specific resources which support your answer to the question